# How can I make a table with x rows and y columns fill the window?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Inside a body tag, I have the following code.

```
<table style="position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;">
<tr>
<td>
<input type="button" value = "cell 1 stuff">
</td>
<td>
<input type = "..." value = "cell 2 stuff">
</td>
... for y columns
</tr>
<tr>
... for x rows
</tr>
</table>
```

I've tried adding width and height attributes to rows and cells, I've tried several other things, mostly from google research, but all my controls and text just group in the top-left corner of the screen.
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Yeah, you have to tell the html how high to be:  but are you sure you want a table for this? It's worth a look at the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/tabular-data.html You might just want some good ol divs depending on what you are doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Set `height:100%` on the html and body elements and

2) Set `width:100%` and `height 100%` on the table element.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/JW5s4/)**

```
html,body
{
    height: 100%;
}
table
{
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works beautifully. I especially appreciated the fiddle, that's a big help.